# Jquery Datepicker action

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to create some actions for my datepickers with jquery bu i cannot.
The actions that i try to make work are:
Out field to be with one day after In field

Form is:

```
<label>Check In</label>
<div class="datepicker-wrap">
<input type="text" name="In" id="In" class="input-text full-width" placeholder="aa/ll/zz" />
</div>
<label>Check Out</label>
<div class="datepicker-wrap">
<input type="text" id="Out" name="Out"class="input-text full-width" placeholder="aa/ll/zz" />
</div>
```

Script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Out").datepicker();
    $("#In").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(){
            var fecha = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $("#Out").datepicker("setDate", new Date(fecha.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        }
    });
});  
</script>
```

Scripts loaded are:

```
<!-- Javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.noconflict.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.2.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.1.10.4.min.js"></script>
```

The script works on jsfiddle but on my site doeas not :(
http://www.bookingassist.ro/site

Comment: And the problem is? It works for me !

Comment: in my my side does not :(